# Cannot create environment in anaconda, update conda , install packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))",),)

Comment: What is your question? Potentially it's blocked by your work network.

Comment: Dupe question without an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53209250/2883245

Answer (score 1):

You are having issues with ssl. Some of these have entered in recent releases for us (using self signed keys) and so we have had to switch ssl_verification off in conda.

This wasn't enough though, and we also had to manually remove the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable that we were using to specify the path to the SSL certificate.

```
# Remove SSL
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

See github issue here - https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10340

Comment: We've gone full circle, haven't we? :-)